# Merge data from two databases, use the row that is most complete/has more fields filled

Tags: mysql, sql

Example:

**Database 1 - Table Client:**

```
id      name        tel     address
1       john        3333    Avenue X
```

**Database 2 - Table Client:**

```
id      name        tel     address
2       john
```

It would have to compare the lines with the same name, check which one has more fields filled, then insert this row into the table 'Client' on database 3.

Result would be:

```
id      name        tel     address
2       john        3333    Avenue X
```